# Java - Accessors Writing Convention

Tags: accessor

I have a generic class, such as the following:

```
public class Test {

private int number = 0;

public Test(number) {
this.number = number;
}
```

My question is as follows, is there any difference between using the following two accessor methods? Which is the best convention?

```
public int getNumber1() {
return number;
}

public int getNumber2() {
return this.number;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference.
However if you have a local variable with the same name (number), the this qualifier enables you to distingruish betweeen a local and a member variable.
So this is just decoration or convention.

Comment: I agree with you. I try to not use `this` as much as possible since it clutters the code. I try to only use it when I need to avoid collisions with regular variable, that is a variable which is declared inside the method or taken as input.